# Performing GET request before leaving page

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, jquery-events, onbeforeunload

If a GET request is made as follows

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    // GET request
});
```

and the page is **abandoned before the GET request is completed**,

**will the destination server still process the request**? Or will it somehow vanish?

---

**I would like to send a server data on `beforeunload` firing, but without stealing useless ms from the user.**

It would be very useful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an asynchronous request then the server may process it (if it receives the request) but I don't know if you can guarantee that the request will go through before the page is unloaded or if it will be processed - this may depend on the actual web server (someone else may have more information). If you make a synchronous request, the page will wait until the request goes through and it gets back a response (so in this case, processing is guaranteed). However, this means that your browser will be locked up until that request completes, which may not be desirable.

Comment: I agree, I wouldn't do it for anything that needs to rely on the request going through.

Comment: @Joe yeah, in general this is not very reliable.

Comment: @Joe @Vivin thanks for the replies! =) There must be a way of achieving more than 90% success ratio?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases yes, but it depends on the web application server. Some can detect the disconnect and stop with the request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! =) I'm using python, and looking into various networking libraries.